# AWS Amplify GraphQL query returns null instead of items array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying to query items from a DynamoDB table using AWS Amplify API, running on React.js.

I have a table named Codes, from which I'm trying to query the items using the following code:

```
var codesData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listCodes, {
  filter: {
    id: {
      eq: id
    },
    num: {
      eq: 1
    }
  }
}));
console.log(codesData);
```

As you can see, I want to receive all items that have `id` value as their "id" attribute, and `1` as their "num" attribute.

When I'm printing the `codesData` to the console, I get the following response:

```
Object
    data:
        listCodes: null
```

So I don't even have the items attribute.

I've tried to search the web for something about that, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: id eq id ... interesting ... documented somewhere ?

Comment: The first id is the name of the attribute from the DB (mentioned in my GraphQL schema). The eq is a short for equal (taken from AWS Amplify documents). The second id is a variable in my code, initialized before the query

Comment: read graphql docs about passing variables

Comment: This is the method to filter results according to Amplify documents

Comment: find example with param/variable

Comment: @xadm I have another query which works, and it is written the same way. The problem is probably related to AWS Amplify and not to GraphQL

Comment: not, this is not the way graphql gets variables ... can work with hardcoded values ... gogole "graphql variables"

Answer (score 0):

In the amplify docs they say that you must create new items after you have added the @searchable directive to your model:

See [GraphQL Transform](https://haverchuck.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js)

and there

`Note: Support for adding the @searchable directive does not yet provide automatic indexing for any existing data to Elasticsearch.`

Create your items anew after you have added @searchable and those items will be displayed.